# Should I use $cordovaSQLite.execute or db.executeSql

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to use Cordova-sqlite-storage in an ionic project, at the beginning I use it as this post(https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/11/use-sqlite-instead-local-storage-ionic-framework/) told me, then I read it's official document (https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage), so I adopted the official way. But after I used `db.transaction{...}` and `db.executeSql(...)`, a problem occurs.  view no longer changes after I updated data, and content no longer displays the first time while entering a view , I have to click a button to make the change takes effect or to show content.

[image]

[image]

see, I have to click a button to show content or make a change takes effect.
Is this issue have something to do with the way I use Cordova-sqlite-storage?

Comment: can you show me your db transaction code ? One more thing after updating the value use $scope.$apply();  see if that works

Comment: you are right, $apply is the answer. But why? I didn't write a single $apply in the first way and everything works just fine.

Comment: $scope.$apply() should occur after async event binding as possible.. ng-click is a function with $appy()at the end .. That's why when you were clicking .. it was working